# DynamoDB filter if primary key contains value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

**CURRENTLY**

I have a table in DynamoDB with a single attribute - Primary Key - that contains unique values.

```
PK
------
#A#B#C#
#B#C#
#C#D#E#
#BC#
```

**ISSUE**

I am looking to do 2 searches for #B#C# (1) exact match, and (2) containing match, and therefore only want results:

```
(1) Exact Match:
#B#C#

(2) Containing Match:
#A#B#C#
#B#C#
```

1. Are these 2 searches possible against the primary key?
2. If so, what is the most efficient query to run? e.g. QUERY or SCAN

**Note:**

For (2) I am using the following code, but it is returning all items in DB:

```
            params = {
                TableName: 'myTable',
                FilterExpression: "contains(#key, :v)",
                ExpressionAttributeNames: { "#key": "PK" },
                ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":v": #B#C# }
            }

            dynamodb.scan(params,callback)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DynamoDB supports two main types of searches: query and scan.  The Query operation finds items based on primary key values.  The Scan operation returns one or more items and item attributes by accessing every item in a table or a secondary index

If you wanted to find the item with a primary key `#B#C`, you would use the [query API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html):

```
ddbClient.query(
  {
    "TableName": "<YOUR TABLE NAME>",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "#pk = :pk",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
      ":pk": {
        "S": "#B#C"
      }
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
      "#pk": "PK"
    }
  }
)
```

For your second access pattern, you'll need to use the scan API because you are searching across the entire table/secondary index.

You can use scan to test if a primary key has a substring using `contains`.  I don't see anything wrong with the format of your scan operation.

Be careful when using scan this way.  Because scan will read your entire table to fetch results, you will have a fairly inefficient operation at scale.  If this operation is run infrequently, or you are running it against a sparse index, it's probably fine.  However, if it's one of your primary access patterns, you may want to reconsider using the scan API for this operation.